# Check if a string ends with something, case insensitive?

Tags: string, case-insensitive, nim-lang

I want to check if a file has a certain extension, which I can do with [`filename.endsWith(".ext")`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/strutils.html#endsWith%2Cstring%2Cstring). But I also want to match against `.EXT`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest is probably `filename.toLowerAscii.endsWith(".ext")`. You should however consider using `splitFile` to get the extension and then simply compare it to `".ext"` after turning it lowercase.

Comment: For those unaware on where that splitfile proc can be found:
https://nim-lang.org/docs/os.html#splitFile%2Cstring.  Usage Example: `let (directory, name, extension) = file.filename.splitFile()`